# PayPal express checkout: checking payment can be performed on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, express-checkout

I'm using PayPal *express checkout* (checkout.js V4.0.0) with *asp.net mvc* to allow a user to pay for data transactions. What I need to do when the express checkout button is clicked is perform some checks on the database and confirm that PayPal can proceed (this is also time related, as the database could be in a *locked* processing state).

I've setup the [Advanced Server Integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/advanced-integration/) and I then call the create-payment controller from the payment section in `paypal.Button.render`, but this expects a `json` object with a `PaymentID` element to be returned. At what point am I able to perform these checks on server side and abort from the paypal process if PayPal can't continue? If a check fails, the server side also needs to return an appropriate error page or message to be displayed.

This is the paypal button code:

```js
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
    paypal.Button.render({
        env: 'sandbox',
        payment: function (resolve, reject) {
            var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL = '@Url.Action("PayTransactions","Pending")';

        paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL)
            .then(function (data) { resolve(data.paymentID); })
            .catch(function (err) { reject(err); });
        },
        onAuthorize: function(data) {
            var EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL = 'https://my-store.com/paypal/execute-payment';

            paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL,
            {
                paymentID: data.paymentID,
                payerID: data.payerID
            })
                .then(function(data) { /* Go to a success page */ })
                .catch(function (err) { /* Go to an error page  */ });
        },
        onCancel: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.redirect();
        },
        onError: function (err) {
            // Show an error page here, when an error occurs
        }
    }, '#paypal-button');
</script>
```

which at the payment section calls this:

```c#
public async Task<string> PayTransactions()
{
    // check if payment is still necessary or end of month is running
    var condition = await CheckDatabaseIsUsable();

    switch (condition)
    {
        case 1:
            ModelState.AddModelError("error", "some error message");
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Pending");

        case 2:
            ModelState.AddModelError("error", "some other error");
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Pending");
    }

    var paypalPayment = FormPayPalPaymentObject();

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { paymentID = paypalPayment.PaymentId });
}
```

The problem is that I am now mixing the `ActionResult` and json `string` return types.

Answer (score 1):

You can return json also for the redirection responses and control with javascript when it is a redirection or and ok response.

Server side:

```
  return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { redirect= Url.Action("Index", "Pending") });
```

Javascript:

```
     paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL)
            .then(function (data) {
                if(data.redirect)
                {
                    //cancel the flow and redirect if needed
                    window.location.href = data.redirect;
                }else{
                    resolve(data.paymentID); 
                }
            })
            .catch(function (err) { reject(err); });
        },
```

Using an `IActionResult` object as the return value for the PayTransactions is preferable

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PayTransactions()
{

    ...

    return Json(new { paymentID = paypalPayment.PaymentId });
}
```

Also consider that the modelstate errors you are adding are useless because of the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `reject(error)` to cancel the payment.

Comment: I've now had a chance to add the code that I'm using, but I'm not sure how I can call `reject(error)` from the mvc controller so that the appropriate error message is displayed.